# How to add 20x20 grid of images in android application

Tags: android, image

I'd like to add 20 (dynamic) images per row and column in a (maybe) grid view. Is there an easy way to solve this without using a .xml in android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you want an *easy* way, you pretty much have to use XML for your layouts.

As for your 20x20 grid, yes, you could use a `GridView`, but I would also suggest using a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`.